vue3-easy-data-table hide until render is ready
I am working on a data table with around 100-200 rows, I intend to load them up in one go with pagination. The rendering takes around 800-1000ms due to the complexity my cell templates, and I am okay with that wait time.
I have hardcoded a timeOut 1000ms to show a circle-spinner and let the table render behind the scenes, it works (in my local testing) but it is a hack, it could fail if other users have a slower device and/or network.
Maybe it is a package-specific issue, or maybe there is a generic solution to a custom component? Is there a way to capture a render complete event, so I don't have to hardcode the 1000ms there?

From docs: "For example, the onMounted hook can be used to run code after the component has finished the initial rendering and created the DOM nodes".

I am aware of onMounted/onUpdate hooks, however, they don't get subsequent calls after the first time vue3-easy-data-table is mounted. (This design is logical, you want the table to update a cell or row inside not the whole component). Only nextTick works, but it seems the table plugin update is not async during render, so UI would just freeze during nextTick executes, and the spinner will not show up during that 800-1000ms. So far, I have only found that a good-old timeOut 1000ms callback works in an async way and allows the spinner to show up. And that leads back to my question.
